# How can I call custom fields in a blog view?

Tags: custom-field

If I do print_r($this->item->jcfields) I see the array.

But when I try to call it in the usual way nothing aooears.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? They don’t appear in Params obviously. But if I can print them then surely I can echo them.

I really want to call separate fields in separate places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the documentation
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Overrides
it provides the technique for accessing individual fields within an override.  So for a field called 'example':

```
<?php
// File location: /templates/templatename/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

// loop first to make the fields easy to reference via the field name as a key
foreach($this->item->jcfields as $jcfield){
    $this->item->arbitrary_property_name[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
}

echo $this->item->introtext; 

echo $this->item->arbitrary_property_name['example']->label; 
echo $this->item->arbitrary_property_name['example']->value; 
?>
```

Also, what do you mean by the 'usual way'? There's like 25+ ways of getting custom fields.

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried this but I could not get it working.  And now when I copy the code I see it working but I only see the label and not the value.  The fields are also showing below the content at the moment so I can see a value exists.  Although oddly they are in a `<p>` and not a `<dl>`.  I must have done something somewhere and forgotten it.  In the above you are saying `arbitrary_property_name` could be anything?

Comment: I meant... my usual way.  Which is `<?php echo $this->item->jcfields[3]->value; ?>`.  That will work in an article but not a blog apparently.  Actually this will also show the label but not the value.  Curiouser and curiouser.  I printed the params but there is no value in there either.  I used `<?php echo "<pre>" . print_r($this->item->jcfields, true) . "</pre>"; ?>`

Comment: Arggghh so much wasted time.  The fields were pasted as content into the main copy and the fields were then not filled in.  How stupid do I have to be!  It must have been working previously because of a different category.

Comment: lol. glad you found your answer, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting not only the script but also the file location ;).

For the article view (single article) use the path above:
// File location: /templates/templatename/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

For the category view (blog) use this path:
// File location: /templates/templatename/html/com_content/article/default.php

You can also style the output directly in the files a bit, for example:

```
<div style="color:#333333; font-weight: 600; font-size:16px;"> 
        <?php
        // File location: /templates/templatename/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

        // loop first to make the fields easy to reference via the field name as a key
        foreach($this->item->jcfields as $jcfield){
            $this->item->arbitrary_property_name[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
        }

        echo $this->item->arbitrary_property_name['example']->label; 
        echo $this->item->arbitrary_property_name['example']->value; 
        ?>
    </div>
```

hope, that helps..

Comment: Great first post. Welcome.to Stack.